# Sum of single column in Joined tables using Linq query and Get One Item from Modal in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am editing question in which i asked for sum of subtotal column. i want to display Customer name and contact along product details in my Cshtml view. and i m using linq joins to show data. products are displayed but dnt know to show customer name and contact on heading. Here is my code

```
public ActionResult GetproductDetails(string id)
        {
            List<tbl_Orders_Details> ODList = null;

            var OD = (from D in db.tbl_Orders_Details
                      join O in db.tbl_Orders
                      on D.Order_ref_No equals O.Refrence_No
                      where D.Order_ref_No == id
                      select new
                      {
                          D.Price,
                          D.product,
                          D.Note,
                          D.Qty,
                          D.Tax_Pkr,
                          D.Discount,
                          D.Subtotal

                      }).ToList();


            ODList = new List<tbl_Orders_Details>();
            foreach (var i in OD)
            {
                tbl_Orders_Details SOD = new tbl_Orders_Details();

                SOD.Price = i.Price;
                SOD.product = i.product;
                SOD.Note = i.Note;
                SOD.Qty = i.Qty;
                SOD.Tax_Pkr = i.Tax_Pkr;
                SOD.Discount = i.Discount;
                SOD.Subtotal = i.Subtotal;
                ODList.Add(SOD);
            }

            return PartialView("GetproductDetails", ODList);

        }
```

Cshtml view

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="text-center"><b>CUSTOMER NAME</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-left">ORDER DATE</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">REFERENCE NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="text-left">CONTACT NUMBER</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">BILLING ADDRESS</td>
    </tr>
</table>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.product</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Note</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Price</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Qty</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Discount</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Tax_Pkr</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@item.Subtotal</td>
                </tr>
            }

    <tr>

                <td colspan="6" class="text-center"><b>@Model.AsEnumerable().Sum(o=>o.Subtotal)</b></td>
            </tr>
```

and modal class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(OrdersDetailsMeta))]
    public partial class tbl_Orders_Details
    {
        public string customer { get; set; }
        public string contact { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrdersDetailsMeta
    {
        public int Order_Detail_ID { get; set; }
        public string Order_ref_No { get; set; }
        public string product { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal Tax_Pkr { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/. But apart from that, why do you join with `Orders`? You don't use its data.

Comment: It also looks like you're copying from one `tbl_Orders_Details`to another for no reason.

Comment: i want to get customer name and contact number from tbl_orders so that i could show it on my detail page. that's why i use the joins..

Comment: I want to get the customer name and contact from tbl_orders. which i don't know how. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in cshtml

```
Model.AsEnumerable().Sum(o=>o.Subtotal);
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i get the customer name and contact number from tbl_order. while tbl_orders_details is List and tbl_orders is single.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you. For this particular question then mark my answer as correct.

Comment: just did it. can you post answer for my second question?

Comment: @B.Mick as per your code what you have pasted here you need to add two more feild in your model class in tbl_Orders_Details and add name and contactnumber field in that. and while you are making join fill the values with O.Name and O.ContactNum. Give a try

Comment: i did the same. but how would i call it in my view.